# Ionic post data to server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I found this solution here, but it doesn't explain a lot so I can modify it to my needs. He is also mentioning a stack overflow question, but there are so many "different" solutions and I got confused.

The controller:

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.data = {};

    $scope.submit = function(){
        var link = 'http://app.domain.com/api.php';

        $http.post(link, {username : $scope.data.username}).then(function (res){
            $scope.response = res.data;
        });
        console($http.post(link, {username : $scope.data.username}));
    };
});
```

I would like modify it and add another field, so it would be username and password. and post the to the server. But the response I need it to be just one field.

Can someone give me an explanation, of the code above so I can modify it?

Comment: If you want to post both username and password, yo can post like this : *{username : $scope.data.username, password: $scope.data.password (only if password exist in $scope.data)}*

Comment: Thanks for your tip NNR. Is it possible for you to give me a brief explanation of the code above? This code is the core of crucial data that will be exchanged over the network. I would like to have a good understanding of the process.

Comment: @Bobys have you seen my answer?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As NNR said, you can pass some other parameters in your HTTP request and then POST it to the endpoint of your choice (here, the link, generally an API endpoint) by submitting it through an ng-submit. 
The request contains your parameters and is parsed into json that you can un-parse later in your php file (in order to get params of the request and then use it in your mysql query (generally..). 
After the request has been sent, it will return you a promise, that will either be a success or an error based on the reply of your server, like this :
`.then(function success(response) { //do stuff here}, 
function error(response) {//do stuff here});` 
You will be able to access that response.data object in your controller by using $scope

 I've some hard time being clear but I hope that helps ! 
I suggest you to have a look at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http ! :)

Comment: Glad I could help :D !